# How to specify row delimiter for Redshift Spectrum

Tags: amazon-redshift, delimiter, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to mount csv files that have a CRLF as a row terminator, into Redshift Spectrum. However, it seems like I can only specify a single character as a row terminator. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: How is it treating the lines if you do not specify the terminator? Is it reading the rows correctly, or is it inserting blank rows?

Comment: Hi John, if I don't specify, it inserts a blank row between each row, which means it's defaulting to CR, and then reads the LF as data. I'm trying to figure out how to specify CRLF as the EOL.